# How to reuse an object in SOAPUI property test step

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

I have a SOAPUI test request which uses a property step.
The property step contains several GUIDs defined as:

```
${=new BigInteger(130, new java.security.SecureRandom()).toString(32)}
```

Is it possible not to instantiate a new SecureRandom for each property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a a Groovy test step, or use the test setup, to assign the answer to a property. Then use that property expansion in your subsequent test steps.

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned code does not generate GUIDs, it generates a random string.

For random GUIDs you should invoke:

```
java.util.UUID.randomUUID()
```

if you need specifically string, you should call toString() after randomUUID:

```
java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```